# Current activity not closing (finish) on Button click

Tags: android

Hi I'm calling an activity with ImageButton click but it would not finish the current activity.

```
btn_home.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View view) {

                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), GridActivity.class);
                i.putExtra("feed", _rssFeed);
                startActivity(i);

                SwipeDetailView.this.finish();
            }
        });
```

However, if I click the home button on the Actionbar menu within the same class, it closes fine.

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {

    case android.R.id.home:

        finish();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: I fixed it. I forgot to add finish() on other activity class. Thanks!

Comment: This is a bad way to ask a question. Please be more attentive in the future to avoid wasting time of the people how are trying to solve your problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are calling finish on the `View.OnClickListener` context instead you need to do `ACTIVITYCLASSNAME.this.finish ()`

Comment: This is the correct way to close the Activity within the OnClickListener.

Comment: I tired ACTIVITYCLASSNAME.this.finish() but it won't work either.

Comment: take note also that the value of R.id.home is not equal to android.R.id.home inside onOptionsItemSelected